# convert list of nested dicts to dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a list of nested dictionaries in python.
I tried to convert it into a dataframe using:

```
data=pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)
```

This converts most of the dicts into columns. However there is still the first column which consists of another list of dicts. Data looks like this:

```
FIS   mid    LI    DE     PBT
     4182    L234  L3133   2020-02-13T09:50:53Z
```

In the `FIS`column are still dictionaries, column first row of `FIS` looks like this:

`[{'FI': [{'TMC': {'PC': 6671, 'DE': 'Pohlheim-Dorf-Güll', 'QD': '+', 'LE': 0.04984}, 'SHP': [], 'CF': [{'TY': 'TR', 'SP': 30.0, 'SU': 30.0, 'FF': 30.0, 'JF': 0.0, 'CN': 0.7}]}`

I tried to applied the method described above again on the `FIS` column. But this doesn't write the dicts in new columns.

So my question is: How can I convert this list of dicts to a dataframe?

I extracted the data from the here api (https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics/examples.html)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It works

```
list_of_dicts = [{"qwerty":[1,2,3]}, {"lol":["l","o","l"]}]
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(e) for e in list_of_dicts], axis=1)
```